# How can I embed a OneDrive video into my HTML in React?

Tags: reactjs, onedrive

I have this [OneDrive URL](https://tranhanh0-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/animedb123_kasuii_xyz/EQtELvF4xR1FsEdRIZ8QhG8BWkNjXQtIQmNE-h0gF1W8Fw?e=fS9zb1) that I want to embed into my HTML in ReactJS.

But whenever I add it into the src attribute of video, nothing is happen, I don't know why it is.

Or else what do I need to do to get these URL types to display on my page.

This is the Component that I use to display the video

```
function AnimeWatch() {

    return (
        <>
        <video width="100%" height="auto" controls>
        <source src = "https://tranhanh0-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/animedb123_kasuii_xyz/EQtELvF4xR1FsEdRIZ8QhG8BWkNjXQtIQmNE-h0gF1W8Fw?e=rKjx06" type = "video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    )
        </>
}
export default AnimeWatch
```

Comment: Whatever the problem is should be reported in the console. Are there any messages in there? Also not sure if its a typo in your question, but you have an open `<>` fragment but no closing tag. That'll be a syntax error and cause React to throw an error.

Comment: Oh, I have the closed fragment in my code but I missed copying it into here due to splash comment of unused code that I've left in this component. But there is an error said "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"

Comment: Try setting `crossOrigin="anonymous"` on the `video` tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-crossorigin

Comment: I've added the crossOrigin at the video tag but still no luck, I'm really new to OneDrive, too, I don't know what I did wrong. It said "Access to video at `URL` has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: Mmm yeah OneDrive may be difficult to deal with if there are redirects, auth checks (even if its public) and such in between the resource. Have a hunt around to see if you can find a bare URL for the video file?

Comment: What do you mean by bare URL file, can you guide me through a little bit? Actually, that video is the one I've uploaded myself and I just try to pull it into my ReactJS, but then this problem occurs. I tried to use OneDrive to store movie in there and pull it into the front-end to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240556/discussion-between-lynden-noye-and-bunny).